# This D3 code is showing <!DOCTYPE> on running. What's the error can not find

Tags: json, d3.js

This D3 code is showing just `<!DOCTYPE>` on running. What's the error can not find. Can't find any error. It reads the data from the JSON file.

```
< !DOCTYPE> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>        
        d3.json("data-02.json"), function(data){
        var x1 = 0,
        y1 = 0,
        x2 = 0,
        y2 = 0,
        total = [],
        totalRadius = 20;

    //executing svg
    var svg = d3.select("#tradingChart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 1000)
        .1ttr("height",600);    

    //division
    var div = d3.select("#tradingChart").append("div")
    .attr("class","tooltip")
    .style("opacity",0);

    //define tooltip
    var tooltip = d3.select("#tradingChart")
    .append("div")
    .style("position","absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility","hidden");

    //making connections with trading values
    data.links.forEach(function(connectingData){
    var source = connectingData.node01;
    var target = connectingData.node02;

    data.nodes.forEach(function(dataNode){
        if (dataNode.id === source){
            x1 = node.dataNode.x;
            y1 = node.dataNode.y;           
            }

        if (dataNode.id === target){
            x2 = dataNode.x;
            y2 = dataNode.y;
            }
    }

    svg.append("line")
        .attr("x1", x1)
        .attr("y1", y1)
        .attr("x2", y2)
        .on("mouseover", function(){
            return tooltip.html(connectingData.node01 + "to" + connectingData.node02 + "<br/> Trading Values:" + connectingData.amount)
                .style("visibility","visible");})
        .on("mouseover", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");})
        .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");})
        .on("mouseout",function(){
            return tooltip.style("visibility","hidden");}
            )
        .attr("stroke","#ccc")
        .attr("strke-width", connectingData.amount / 50);   
        }); 

    //making nodes based on total trading values
        data.nodes.forEach(function(dataNode){
        var siteName = dataNode.id;
        total[siteName] = 0;

        data.links.forEach(function(dataNode){
            if(connectingData.node01 ===siteName || connectingData.node02 === siteName){
                total[siteName] = total[siteName] + connectingData.amount;
                }

        });

        var circle = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", dataNode.x)
            .attr("cy", dataNode.y)
            .attr("r", calculateRadius(connectingData.id))
                .on("mouseover", function(){
                    return tooltop.html(dataNode.id + "<br/>Trading Value:" + total[dataNode.id])
                        .style("visibility", "visible");})
                .on("mousemove",function(){return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left", (event.pageX+10)+"px");})
                .on("mouseout", function(){
                    return tooltip.style("visibility","hidden");})
            .attr("fill","#027c96");        

                });
        function calculateRadius(id){
            return total[id] * totalRadius/1000;
        }
        });




});
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to run with errors in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqeonv7m/1/)

Open up the console on chrome to see the errors. I went ahead and fixed your first mistake which was jsut a minor typing error.

```
//executing svg
var svg = d3.select("#tradingChart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .1ttr("height",600);
```

.1ttr should be .attr

After fixing that it looks like you have some other errors to handle. I'm getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" on line VM219:88, which is the " });" at the end of

```
    var circle = svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", dataNode.x)
        .attr("cy", dataNode.y)
        .attr("r", calculateRadius(connectingData.id))
            .on("mouseover", function(){
                return tooltop.html(dataNode.id + "<br/>Trading Value:" + total[dataNode.id])
                    .style("visibility", "visible");})
            .on("mousemove",function(){return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left", (event.pageX+10)+"px");})
            .on("mouseout", function(){
                return tooltip.style("visibility","hidden");})
        .attr("fill","#027c96");        

            });
```